# Snapshot API not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running ES 2.4.4 and trying to use the snapshot API but I 'm getting the following error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"exception","reason":"failed to create blob container"}],"type":"exception","reason":"failed to create blob container","caused_by":{"type":"access_denied_exception","reason":"/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/es_snapshots/tests-JyPFj3wmSCq3UaxKnZcSAA"}},"status":500}
```

The command I've used to run the snapshot API is :

```
curl -XPUT -u user:passwd -k 'https://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' -d '{ "type": "fs", "settings": { "location": "/var/lib/es_snapshots", "compress": true } }'
```

I've also used the same command with a different location:

```
curl -XPUT -u user:passwd -k 'https://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_backup' -d '{ "type": "fs", "settings": { "location": "/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/es_snapshots", "compress": true } }'
```

The path configurations for my ES look like this:

```
"path" : {
      "conf" : "/etc/elasticsearch",
      "data" : "/var/lib/elasticsearch/data",
      "logs" : "/var/log/elasticsearch",
      "home" : "/usr/share/elasticsearch",
      "repo" : [ "/var/lib/es_snapshots", "/var/lib/elasticsearch/data/es_snapshots" ]
    }
```

Comment: Seems like a permission issue. Tried running curl using sudo ?

Comment: what is the role and permission assigned to esadmin user .

Comment: @user3775217 the esadmin user is an admin user

Answer (score 3):

1. Check your path.repo:

   ```
    sudo vim /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
   ```
2. Must be something like that path.repo: ["/home/xxxx/backups"]
3. You should check if user elasticsearch have write permission here /home/xxxx/backups, using:

   ```
    sudo -u elasticsearch touch /home/xxxx/backups/TEST.TXT
   ```
4. If it don't have, then use

   ```
    sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /home/xxxx/backups
   ```
5. Try again